# IIS URLRewrite Add Mapping Entry Powershell

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I want to add a mapping entry by power shell.
Is anyone teach me how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: What mapping entry are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this command  to create map rule first

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rewriteMaps" -name "." -value @{name='myrewritemap'}
```

If you already have a map rule and you just want to add map entry, then you could use this command:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rewriteMaps/rewriteMap[@name='myrewritemap']" -name "." -value @{key='/some-title';value='/article.aspx?id=1&title=some-title'}
```